# PigLatin map key value

Tags: dictionary, hadoop, apache-pig

I'm working with some PigLatin code for the first time and want to be able to access values in a map by first generating the key value as a chararray, and then using that key. For example, with categoryIds being my map,

```
catIds = foreach filteredContexts generate elementId,SUBSTRING(categoryAndConfidence,0,2) as catId;
categoryNames = foreach catIds generate elementId, categoryIds#catId as catName;
```

This is the error I'm receiving:
ERROR 1000: Error during parsing. Encountered "  "catId "" at line 28, column 64.
Was expecting one of:
    "null" ...
     ...
     ...
    "null" ...

Is what I'm trying to do not possible? Do I need to explicitly state the key value (eg: categoryIds#'51') every time I use a map?

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know, Pig doesn't provide any built in way to get key from a map. With a map field, you can only get its size using SIZE function, check if it's empty using IsEmpty function, or use map_field#'key' to look up the value of given key.

I myself wrote some UDFs to help me better work on map data type. One of my function might be useful for you - MapToBag - which can convert a map `:map[value_type]` to a bag `:bag{:tuple(key:chararray, value:value_type)}`. With the bag, you can either get the key, or apply FLATTEN operation.

```
package com.XXX.YYY.ZZZ;

import org.apache.pig.EvalFunc;
import org.apache.pig.FuncSpec;
import org.apache.pig.data.*;
import org.apache.pig.impl.logicalLayer.FrontendException;
import org.apache.pig.impl.logicalLayer.schema.Schema;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

public class MapToBag extends EvalFunc<DataBag> {

    @Override
    public DataBag exec(Tuple input) throws IOException {
        if (input == null || input.size() == 0) {
            return null;
        }

        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        Map<String, Object> map = (Map<String, Object>) input.get(0);
        if (map == null || map.isEmpty()) {
            return null;
        }

        DataBag bag = bagFactory.newDefaultBag();
        for (String key : map.keySet()) {
            Object value = map.get(key);
            Tuple oneKeyTuple = tupleFactory.newTuple(2);
            oneKeyTuple.set(0, key);
            oneKeyTuple.set(1, value);
            bag.add(oneKeyTuple);
        }

        return (bag.size() == 0) ? null : bag;
    }

    @Override
    public Schema outputSchema(Schema input) {
        try {
            Schema innerSchema = new Schema();
            innerSchema.add(new Schema.FieldSchema("key", DataType.CHARARRAY));
            innerSchema.add(getMapValueSchema(input));
            Schema tupleSchema = new Schema(new Schema.FieldSchema(null, innerSchema, DataType.TUPLE));
            return new Schema(new Schema.FieldSchema(null, tupleSchema, DataType.BAG));
        } catch (FrontendException e) {
            return new Schema(new Schema.FieldSchema(null, DataType.BAG));
        }
    }

    protected Schema.FieldSchema getMapValueSchema(Schema input) throws FrontendException {
        if (input == null || input.size() == 0) {
            return null;
        }
        Schema.FieldSchema mapField = input.getField(0);
        if (mapField.type != DataType.MAP) {
            return null;
        }

        Schema valueSchema = mapField.schema;
        if (valueSchema == null || valueSchema.size() == 0) {
            return null;
        }
        Schema.FieldSchema valueField = valueSchema.getField(0);
        valueField.alias = "value";
        return valueField;
    }

    @Override
    public List<FuncSpec> getArgToFuncMapping() throws FrontendException {
        List<FuncSpec> funcList = new ArrayList<FuncSpec>();
        funcList.add(new FuncSpec(this.getClass().getName(), new Schema(new Schema.FieldSchema(null, DataType.MAP))));
        return funcList;
    }

    private static TupleFactory tupleFactory = TupleFactory.getInstance();
    private static BagFactory bagFactory = BagFactory.getInstance();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your code, `catIds` only has two fields - `elementId` and `catId`, and you are trying to access `categoryIds` in the second line. So it won't work. Please fix it.

Specifically as to how to access map values, you need to enclose the key in quotes, e.g `categoryIds#'catId'`